# get URL's array from multiple script tags as string

Tags: javascript

I need to write a javascript code to return all scripts url as array

```
var x='<script src="js/templates/templates.combined.js"></script><script src="js/anuj-ajaxService.js"></script><script src="js/anuj-algos.js"></script><script src="js/anuj-utils.js"></script><script src="js/anuj-scrolling.js"></script><script src="js/anuj-handlebarHelpers.js"></script><script src="js/anuj-global.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-header/js/anuj-header.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-menu/js/anuj-menu.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-sections-nav/js/anuj-sections-nav.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-section--action/js/anuj-section--action.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-section--content/js/anuj-section--content.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-carousel/js/anuj-carousel.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-advisers/js/personalise.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-advisers/js/anuj-advisers.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-testimonials/js/anuj-testimonials.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-section--lifestage/js/anuj-section--lifestage.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-section--personalise/js/anuj-section--personalise-conversation.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-search/js/anuj-search.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-forms-docs/js/anuj-forms-docs.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-thought-leadership/js/anuj-thought-leadership.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-video/js/anuj-video.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-sitemap/js/anuj-sitemap.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-section--mjo/js/anuj-section--mjo.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-section--mjo/js/anuj-section--mjo--validation.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-section--mjo/js/anuj-section-mjo--insurance.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-profile-overlay/js/anuj-profile-overlay.js"></script><script src="modules/anuj-sitemap/js/anuj-tabbed.js"></script>';
```

The above would return

`["js/templates/templates.combined.js","js/anuj-ajaxService.js","js/anuj-algos.js"...]` so on..

Comment: i tried replace , splits and toStrings multiple times can not get the desired output

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see how to write a proper question. In this case it even sounds like homework. Post your code

Comment: Write a regular expression that parses everything between src=" and the next " . Or split on </script> and then split each piece on src=" . Or just create an element, append the scripts with innerHTML and just loop over the script nodes. So many options...

Comment: `x.match(/"(.*?)"/g);` but your `/script` needs to be escaped in the string `\/script`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aH9zN7/1

Answer (score 0):

If I catch your question correctly, this should do the job.

```
x
 .replace(/<script src=\"/g, "")
 .split("\"></script>")
 .filter(x=>x.length)
```